# How to write formula in .md file for hugo website

Tags: r, markdown, hugo

I have my .md file from hugo website and have my formula written as below. It works in .rmd file, but not in hugo .md file. The output html file (html interpretation) I get from this is also shown below. What do I need to get this interpreted properly?

```
---
title: "Arrays"
date: 2019-08-15T17:26:23-05:00
draft: false
output: html_document
---

$$
\begin{aligned} 
 CV & = \left\{
 \begin{array}{cccccc}
     8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28  \\
     8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28  \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots \\
     8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28  \\
   \end{array}
   \right\} \\
   & \\
 \%Diff & = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
     5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5  \\
     10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
     25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \\
   \end{array}
   \right\}
\end{aligned} 
$$
```

Html interpretation of above formula:

> [ \begin{aligned} CV & = \left{ \begin{array}{cccccc} 8 & 12 & 16 &
>   20 & 24 & 28 \ 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 \ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
>   & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \ 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 \
>   \end{array} \right} \ & \ \%Diff & = \left{ \begin{array}{ccccc} 5
>   & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \ 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
>   & \vdots & \vdots \ 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \ \end{array} \right}
>   \end{aligned} ]

Expected html output:
[image]

Comment: You'll have to check whether your Hugo setup [has MathJax enabled](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#mathjax-with-hugo). I *think* that's something that happens at the theme level, e.g. your current theme might not have it and you can add it.

Comment: @Marius please make this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Marius suggested in the comments, [MathJax](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#mathjax-with-hugo) is the way to go if you want to use mathematical formulas. If you want to incorporate it, first check your theme docs - it might be enough to enable MathJax by merely adding an option in the frontmatter.
Beware of the LaTeX-style formula issues when working with markdown(written in hugo docs).